# BackButton without text SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui, navigationbar, back-button

Actually, this is the question.
I have a screen like this, I would like to change the BackButton.

My View screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHItd.png)

I want instead of blue backbutton with standart array + text BACK, just to be black array WITHOUT text.

In other words, essentially remove the text from the backbutton and change the color to black. How not to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the appropriate modifiers inside the View you wish to be black and without text. You need to specify *no button* and supply your own image as well as the return functionality.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
            Text("Second view")
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
            self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black))
    }
}
```

Edited: Inserted the appropriate image.

Comment: the problem is that this way the icon will not appear immediately after switching to the new view, but let's say in 0.5 seconds, which is very noticeable in the soy queue. How can I avoid this?

Comment: There should be no delay in a navigationBarItem displaying. This is Apple's way to add buttons to the navBar - they wouldn't implement a slow system for something so important. Your system must be under a heavy, artificial load. Have you tried it on a real device? It appears instantaneously.